# Creating md-cards as links in Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Putting an anchor tag `("[routerLink]")` around the whole component containing the card is altering the styling (creating a link class to try to disable styling didn't help).

What's the correct way to dynamically create (e.g., ngFor) cards (md-card in this case) as clickable links?

In other words, each card is clickable and links to a different view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not required to use a routerLink you can use a click event and navigate from inside your component.

Example Component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

interface Thing{
    name:string;
    route:string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-things',
    template: `
        <md-card *ngFor="let thing of things" (click)="navigate(thing)">
            Simple card
        </md-card>
    `
})
export class ThingsComponent implements OnInit {
    things: Thing[];

    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) { 
        //todo initialize things
    }

    navigate(thing:Thing){
        this.router.navigate(thing.route);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks. That helped clear it up. I have one follow-up. I'm trying to put it into a template but I'm not sure how to specify that the link should come from the HTML. Interpolation isn't working for this, but it does for everything else. <md-card (click)="redirect({{redirectLink}})">

Comment: Just curious, but why the `{{}}` binding in the click event? If the redirect link is available in the component why not just use `(click)="redirect()"` and in the redirect function in your component use the redirectLink property e.g. `this.router.navigate(this.redirectLink);`

Comment: <face palm/> ... not sure how I missed that. THANKS!! All working now.